searching for free and portable (no installation needed) general ledger - accounting software for windows
I'm searching for free and portable (no installation needed) general ledger - accounting software for windows.
Please recommend if such thing is available.
and it should work offline
all data and software must be local.
I know about gnucash.
But are there any other options.

What country are you in? Not only are accounting requirements slightly different, there is atleast one company which will provide this for US customers only.

You could try the Portable Apps build of GNUCash this should:

Run anywhere (cloud, removable (e.g. USB drive), local) without 'installing'.
Double-Entry Accounting
Bank/Liability/Expense Accounts
Stock/Bond/Mutual Fund Accounts
Small-Business Accounting (Customers, Vendors, Jobs, Invoices, Accounts Payable/Receivable)
QIF/OFX/HBCI Import, Transaction Matching
Reports, Graphs
Scheduled Transactions
Financial Calculations
Online banking with specific institutions (requires running as admin)

GNUCash itself is completely Free, Open Source, GPL Licenced & Cross Platform but the Portable Apps Build is Windows Specific however the data it stores should still be accessible from Linux & Mac builds of GNUCash.
There is lots of online help in the manual & the Wiki in multiple languages, multiple mailing lists.
GNUCash has been actively developed & maintained since 1998 with 5.10 being released 15th Dec 2024 but the PortableApps builds tending to run a couple of releases behind (5.8 at the time of writing).
Note that GNUCash is intended for Personal & Small Business use so is probably not suitable for larger organisations.
Note that all data is stored offline by default. It is also worth noting that GNUCash is able to provide a user interface in multiple languages and adding additional translations is relatively painless as is setting local taxation rates.

I've downloaded gnucash from the portable apps site
but I need to see other options before settling on anything.
May be I should have mentioned that in my question.
I'll edit it.

If you are in USA then Wave Accounting Software provides online software.  So its portable and no installation is required.
For US customers it is free.  The caveat is that they clip the ticket on any payments made to you via credit card.  If you don't receive any such payments, there is no charge.
Disclaimer - I am not associated with them.

I need it to work offline

I live in the middle east
